# How can I correctly handle this custom login in a Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I pretty new in PHP and absolutely new in **Laravel** and I have the following problem.

I am using Laravel to develop a **front end** application (so I use it only for **route**, **controller** and **view**). All the business logic is implemented by a **Java back end** application implementing REST web services.

I know that Laravel provide a pretty well done automatic login system creation using the statement:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

The problem is that this system directly interact with the database.

In my case the Laravel application have only to interact with the Java back end application (it is this application that interact with the database). So this system is not appropriate for me. At this development stage we have no token.

Basically the Laravel front end application is something like this:

1) A **view** showing the login form (username and password).

2) A **controller** class that contains a method that receive the submit of the previous form and that call the REST web service of the back end application (doing request having an **authorization header** containing the inserted username and password.

The backend application will return (into to previous Laravel controller method) a **JSON** containing the user information like this as response:

```
{
  "userName": "Painkiller",
  "email": "painkiller@gmail.com",
  "enabled": true
}
```

or, in case the user is not authorized, something like this

```
{
  "timestamp": 1485183649134,
  "status": 401,
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "Credenziali non valide",
  "path": "/Extranet/login"
}
```

So basically if the user in authenticate (if the Laravel controller receive the first JSON type), the JSON object i converted into a **PHP model object** representing the logged user, this object is put into the session and the user is redirected to the following page.

Could be a neat solution? or can create some kind of problem?

And here another doubt. Into the Laravel project structure I have the **App\Http\Controllers\Auth** namespace containing the autogenerated **LoginController** class, this:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
}
```

From what I understood this class should be used for the Laravel native login system (the one implemented performing the **php artisan make:auth** statement).

So is it maybe better create a new controller class for my custom login that involves the call of my back end web service? Or what?

Comment: if you are not planing to use default laravel registration scaffold and save the user into the DB then yes, create a custom controller for login...but then you are on your own! there is no that much documentation about that as if you would create it the laravel way

Comment: @lewis4u no I can't use the default laravel registration because all the interaction with the database are made using REST API implemented by my Java back end application. I need use Laravel only for the pure front end purpose (no business logic). My only doubt is related to put the obtained object (the one related to the logged user returned by my web service) into the session and redirect to the next page. I am not so into front end development (I am working more on the BE) and I don't know if it is a neat solution

Comment: Sorry I don't know either

Comment: I don't have any experience in this but your problem looks like it could be ideally solved using a custom Authentication Guard... https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#adding-custom-guards

Comment: How are you suppose to authenticate each request from the logged in user between Laravel and your Java BE? Or does your BE provide you with some jwt token or similar?

Comment: @RikardOlsson I am not so into FE...I have no token. The idea is: the user insert username and password into the login, the BE web service is called and return a JSON object representing the logged user information. These data will be put into session so I think that these information will be accessible from other page untill the section expires.Could be a solution?

Comment: Ok! I'm guessing your Java BE also putting Laravel's data into a session var. So if that's the case then the request/response path looks like this: Browser/FE <-> Laravels HTTP layer (storing info of FE) <-> Java BE (storing info of your Laravel server), which in theory should make the middle step unnecessary - but I understand your problem. Maybe it would work ok for you just using FE stuff, like Angular?

Answer (score 1):

You can overright any method of the **AuthenticatesUsers** trait inside the LoginController. And thus, have the full control of what the build-in controller does.